# Adding a Panel into a Panel

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc, extjs4.1

I have a `card` layout set in my app.js. here's the code;

```
...
launch: function() {
        var vp = Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'card',
            items: [
            {
                xtype: 'doctor'
            },
            {
                xtype:'nurse'
            }
            ]
        });
    }, ...
```

and, the first view that will load. here's the code;

```
Ext.define('RoyProject.view.user.Doctor', {
    extend:'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.doctor',
    id:'docform', 
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    items: [{       
        fieldLabel: 'Name',
        name: 'name'
        }],
    buttons: [, {
        text: 'Send',
        action:'send'        
    }]
});
```

Since i am using `card` layout in the app.js, all the first view has got stretched out, and occupies the whole screen. Therefore, to get rid of this i thought to add a `Panel` and within that `Panel` to add my view (which is `RoyProject.view.user.Doctor`). Can someone help me to add this view into a Panel, without changing the logic of the code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to solve wrong problem. You don't need to enclose your `doctor` panel into another one. In general idea of nesting panels one inside another is bad...

What you need to do is to either specify fixed width for your `doctor` panel or play is its layout to see which one fits you better.

Comment: specifying width height made no change for the stretch effect.

Comment: Well, according to @CD.. answer it works. Do you think it is the correct approach to follow ?

Comment: I really think @sha is right. nesting panels isn't a good approach, but I've just answered your question...

Answer (score 1):

```
launch: function() {
        var vp = Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'card',
            items: [
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                items: { xtype: 'doctor' }
            },
            {
                xtype:'nurse'
            }
            ]
        });
    }, ...
```